# Calling Email Service from Process builder

Tags: process-builder, apex-email-service, macros

We have a requirement where we have to send an email to a `case's` related `Contact`.

We are trying combination of `Macros (Service Cloud) and process builder`.

1) We have tried with `process builder` to send the `email alert` to `case's` Contact. But, `Process builder` doesn't have `look up` functionality.

So, my question is can we call an `Email Service` from a  `process builder`?

Comment: There is easier work around. Create a formula field on case that points to contact's email id. Then you can use this case formula field in your process builder.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use traditional workflow?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the DML event is on `Case`, then the Process Builder flows on `Case` will be evaluated using their triggering criteria to see which are true.

For those Process Builder flows triggered true, if one has an immediate action Email Alert, such Email Alert can send the email to the related Contact on Case.

Email Alerts define the recipients, not the Process itself (which only supplies the target object).

[image]